# Can i use objects build in the server to set up the interface inputs in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building an app with R Shiny.

I take an Excel file as input with the browser and then I process the file in the server via a reactive function. What I want to know is to use the factors in a specific column as input parameters for the user.
For example I have a column which contains countries: France, Germany, USA, UK etc ... I want the user to have the option to select columns with selectizeInput using the country of the column in my dataframe which is in the server.

Hope my question is clear.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, use uiOutput() to define an input object - the name goes within the parentheses.

On the server side, user renderUI to associate your list of countries with the above object.

Have a look at the official docs at:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html

Cheers.